# maintain scattered elements in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need an efficient way to put these elements as following:

- a back button on the top left
- some element in the middle wrapped in `Column()`

usually I use `Row()` and `Column()` widgets but I don't think that's the case here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of UI, I prefer using [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html).

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        // for future cases
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                left: 16,
                top: 16,
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),// use backButton widget
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [Text("A")],// your widgtes
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

> Widgets are prioritized bottom to top.